# How to add android phone contact to groups according to group_id

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am working on a contact list project and so far i can want to add contacts that are already in phone to group according to group id. i have find group id from the following code.

```
final String[] GROUP_PROJECTION = new String[] {ContactsContract.Groups._ID, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE };

Cursor cursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,GROUP_PROJECTION, null, null, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE+ " ASC");
```

now i want to pick some contact from phone and insert these contact to specific group according to these group ids.

Thank you in advance